# Why is select.select telling me it is not readable

Tags: python-3.x, pipe, file-descriptor

There behaviour of the following minimal code seems incorrect. Why does the second select.select fail to find the remaining line. Is there a buffering somewhere and how do I expose the correct buffer?

```
import select
import os

read, write = os.pipe()
writeable = os.fdopen(write, "w")
readable = os.fdopen(read, "r")
writeable.write("first\n")
writeable.write("second\n")
writeable.flush()
if select.select([readable], [], [], 10)[0][0] == readable:
    print(readable.readline())

print(str(select.select([readable], [], [], 1)))
print(readable.readline())
```

--- Results:

```
first

([], [], [])
second
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is due to buffering. I couldn't find any concrete documentation but it looks like the full input is being pulled into the buffer when you first call `readline`.

You can specify no buffering as the third variable in fdopen, but it isn't allowed for text, throwing

```
ValueError: can't have unbuffered text I/O
```

If you make the input a byte stream which does allow for unbuffered I/O, you can see the difference (Changes marked with comments):

```
import select
import os

read, write = os.pipe()

# Use a byte stream and add 0 to disable buffering
writeable = os.fdopen(write, "wb", 0)
readable = os.fdopen(read, "rb", 0)

# Write in bytes
writeable.write(b"first\n")
writeable.write(b"second\n")
writeable.flush()

if select.select([readable], [], [], 10)[0][0] == readable:
    print(readable.readline())

print(str(select.select([readable], [], [], 1)))
print(readable.readline())

# Do another check on select.
print(str(select.select([readable], [], [], 1)))
```

Doing this gives us an output of:

```
>>>b'first\n'
>>>([<_io.FileIO name=4 mode='rb' closefd=True>], [], [])
>>>b'second\n'
>>>([], [], [])
```

which I'd guess is the behaviour you were expecting, and if you then remove the disable buffering 0 variable from the `fdopen` calls,

```
writeable = os.fdopen(write, "wb")
readable = os.fdopen(read, "rb")
```

you get back:

```
>>>b'first\n'
>>>([], [], [])
>>>b'second\n'
>>>([], [], [])
```

As in your original example.